# compare datetime values just by date

Tags: c#

i wish to compare to datetime values just by date, not by hour. How can i do so ?

I want to remove some values that are outside an interval selected by me :

```
if (DateTime.Compare(DateTime.Parse(t.Rows[i][1].ToString().Trim()), dateTimePicker1.Value) < 0 || DateTime.Compare(DateTime.Parse(t.Rows[i][1].ToString().Trim()), dateTimePicker2.Value) > 0) 
/*remove comand*/
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the `DateTime.Date`property for this, since this contains only the date part of the `DateTime`object.

```
if (DateTime.Compare(DateTime.Parse(t.Rows[i][1].ToString().Trim()).Date,
    dateTimePicker1.Value.Date) < 0 || DateTime.Compare(DateTime.Parse(t.Rows[i][1].ToString().Trim()).Date, 
    dateTimePicker2.Value.Date) > 0))
```

Do not forget to check about the UTC or timestamp value if exists.

Answer (score 5):

Be also aware of Utc and Locale issue.
For me it's important to do all compare in Utc !

So do something like

```
Datetime d1, d2;
d1 = d1.toUniversalTime().Date;
d2 = d2.toUniversalTime().Date;
if(DateTime.Compare(d1, d2))....
```

Answer (score 4):

```
DateTime d1, d2';

...

// following will compare by date and time both
d1 == d2

// following will compare by date only
d1.Date == d2.Date
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Date property like this:

```
DateTime currentTime = Datetime.Now;
DateTime aBitEarlier = currentTime.AddHours(-5).AddMinutes(-4);

if (currentTime.Date == aBitEarlier.Date)
{
    ...
}
```

So in your case:

```
if (DateTime.Compare(DateTime.Parse(t.Rows[i][1].ToString().Trim()).Date, dateTimePicker1.Value.Date) < 0 || DateTime.Compare(DateTime.Parse(t.Rows[i][1].ToString().Trim()).Date, dateTimePicker2.Value.Date) > 0)
{
    ...
}
```